# How to implement web service consumer SOAP with Mulesoft

Tags: soap-client, mule-studio, mule-component

I'd like to implement web service consumer with mulesoft. I have followed the guide of Mule at address: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer . When I have arrived to insert Data mapper Trasformer I have seen that the windows for setting parameters don't pre-populates. 
Why?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first step of using web service-consumer was to drag the the web-service consumer component into to flow by defining required parameters like wsdl url. Then drag the datampper before the ws-consumer component which load the ws definition to the traget side of datamapper.

Comment: it works. I had a raggiungibility problem of the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Web Service Consumer. On the bottom right hand side of Studio you should have the DataSense Explorer. Do you have anything listed under "Payload"? If not, then chances are that Studio is not loading DataSense from your WSDL file.

Try clicking on "Refresh Metadata" if this is the case.